# Integer compression method

Tags: database, algorithm, math, integer, compression

How can I compress a row of integers into something shorter ?

Like:
 Input: '1 2 4 5 3 5 2 3 1 2 3 4' -> Algorithm -> Output: 'X Y Z'

and can get it back the other way around? ('X Y Z' -> '1 2 4 5 3 5 2 3 1 2 3 4')
Note:Input will only contain numbers between 1-5 and the total string  of number will be 10-16
Is there any way I can compress it to 3-5 numbers?

Comment: Since you have five possibilities for each "number" that is 2.322 bits of entropy per number. If you have at most 16 such numbers then you have at most 37.15 bits of entropy in the entire sequence. This certainly fits within a 64-bit integer as @user3386109 noted. A trivial way to encode this is to simply use consecutive 3-bit fields for each "number".

Comment: In JS you may do like `parseInt("013424120123",5).toString(36);` and get `ad65j`. Your digits has to be mapped to 0-4 though. For reverse do like `parseInt("ad65j",36).toString(5);` and get `13424120123`. Add required many `0`s to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. First, subtract one from each of your little numbers. For your example input that results in

```
0 1 3 4 2 4 1 2 0 1 2 3
```

Now treat that as the base-5 representation of an integer. (You can choose either most significant digit first or last.) Calculate the number in binary that means the same thing. Now you have a single integer that "compressed" your string of little numbers. Since you have shown no code of your own, I'll just stop here. You should be able to implement this easily.

Since you will have at most 16 little numbers, the maximum resulting value from that algorithm will be `5^16` which is `152,587,890,625`. This fits into `38` bits. If you need to store smaller numbers than that, convert your resulting value into another, larger number base, such as `2^16` or `2^32`. The former would result in 3 numbers, the latter in 2.

---

@SergGr points out in a comment that this method does not show the number of integers encoded. If that is not stored separately, that can be a problem, since the method does not distinguish between leading zeros and coded zeros. There are several ways to handle that, if you need the number of integers included in the compression. You could require the most significant digit to be `1` (first or last depends on where the most significant number is.) This increases the number of bits by one, so you now may need `39` bits.

Here is a ***toy example of variable length encoding***. Assume we want to encode two strings: `1 2 3` and `1 2 3 0 0`. How the results will be different? Let's consider two base-5 numbers `321` and `00321`. They represent the same value but still let's convert them into base-2 preserving the padding.

```
1 + 2*5 + 3*5^2 = 86 dec = 1010110 bin
1 + 2*5 + 3*5^2 + 0*5^3 + 0*5^4 = 000001010110 bin
```

Those additional `0` in the second line mean that the biggest 5-digit base-5 number `44444` has a base-2 representation of `110000110100` so the binary representation of the number is padded to the same size.

Note that there is no need to pad the first line because the biggest 3-digit base-5 number `444` has a base-2 representation of `1111100` i.e. of the same length. For an initial string `3 2 1` some padding will be required in this case as well, so padding might be required even if the top digits are not `0`.

Now lets add the most significant `1` to the binary representations and that will be our encoded values

```
1 2 3 => 11010110 binary = 214 dec
1 2 3 0 0 => 1000001010110 binary = 4182 dec
```

There are many ways to decode those values back. One of the simplest (but not the most efficient) is to first calculate the number of base-5 digits by calculating `floor(log5(encoded))` and then remove the top bit and fill the digits one by one using mod 5  and divide by 5 operations.

Obviously such encoding of variable-length always adds exactly 1 bit of overhead.

Comment: This sounds like a good start but I think it doesn't cover the variable number of integers to be compressed.

Comment: @SergGr: I assumed that the number of integers was stored or calculated separately. That may be a bad assumption, so I'll add something about that to my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `There are several ways to handle [10-16 total]` true. `if you need the number of integers included` think of a file storing gazillions of `[rows] of integers`. Requiring one symbol with a constant value doesn't help telling bounds if used to encode values, alternatively - first rule of testing compression/encoding ideas: *create a working decoder*. One way to handle *10-16 total* is allowing an additional *place not used* for places 11-15 for a total of 5^11*6^5=379687500000 combinations - ≤ five digits with base ≥ 207 or 39 bits. (How *did* you arrive at `38`?)

Comment: @greybeard I think you missed what Rory suggests. First of all it is obvious from the information point of view that if you can encode all sequence of size `N` with `M` bits you can encode all sequences of size _`N` or less_ using at most `M+1` bits because obviously the number of sequences of size less than `N` is smaller than the number of sequences of size exactly `N`. Actually this additional bit theoretically might be not even required but it is required in Rory's approach. I added a toy example of variable length encoding to the Rory's answer. Let me now if you see some issues with that.

Comment: @SergGr: (`Let me` *know*?) `I think [greybeard] missed what Rory suggests` I claim adding a symbol of fixed value in a fixed position does not add information. How do you decode `110101101000001010110` or `100000101011011010110`?

Comment: @greybeard, first of all not every bit string is a valid encoding of some sequence: there are more bit strings than sequences so some are invalid and it so happened that both of your examples are invalid. Particularly following the encoding algorithm you can get only bit strings of length 1,4,6,8,11,13,15,18,20,22,... Your strings are of length 21 which is impossible. But if you consider `1000001010110110101100` (your second value with one more `0` at the end), it is a valid string. It represents a decimal value of `2141612`. `ceil(log5(2141612))` is `9`, so it was a sequence of 9 numbers.

Comment: Now calculate the values. Remove the top bit and we get `000001010110110101100` which in decimal is `44460`. 1. If we divide `44460` by 5 we get `8892` and `0` as reminder so the first value is `0`. 2. Then `8892` = `1778*5 + 2`. 3. `1778` = '355*5 + 3` 4. `355` = `71*5 + 0` 5. `71` = `14*5 + 1` 6. `14` = `2*5 + 4` 7. `2` = `0*5 + 2` 8. `0` = `0*5 + 0` 9. `0` = `0*5 + 0`. Collecting all the reminders we get initial sequence as `0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0`. You can easily verify yourself that encoding of this sequence does give that bit string because it is just decoding in the reverse order.

Comment: On the logical level I believe the wrong claim is the part about "_in a fixed position_". The position of the added bit is not fixed. It is different for different lengths of the original sequences and thus easily can and actually does convey the information about the length of the original sequence as you can see in my example. Encoding of `0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2` is `101010110110101100`; encoding of  `0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0` is `10001010110110101100` and encoding of `0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0` is `1000001010110110101100` and they differ exactly in the position of the highest bit.

Comment: @SergGr: `Your strings are […] impossible. [1000001010110110101100] is a valid string. It represents  […] a sequence of 9 numbers.` Both are just the concatenations of the bit strings from "the 1 2 3 example".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185579/discussion-between-serggr-and-greybeard).

Answer (score 0):

Its call : **polidatacompressor.js** but license will be cost you, you have to ask author about prices LOL

https://github.com/polidatacompressor/polidatacompressor

Ncomp(65535)  will output: 255, 255  and when you store this in database as bytes you got 2 char

another way is to use "Hexadecimal aka base16" in javascript (1231).toString(16) give you '4cf' in 60% situation it compress char by -1

Or use base10 to base64 https://github.com/base62/base62.js/
4131 --> 14D
413131 --> 1Jtp